# enum and struct call

Tags: c++, struct, enums, compiler-errors, initialization

I have a header file called Status.h shown in part below:

```
enum State {
    OFFLINE = 0,
    ONLINE = 1,
    ...
};

struct AgentStatus {
    State statusInfo;
...
};
```

In my .cpp file I want to initialize this struct, set the status, and make a call to find the state every 10 seconds. This is my attempt:

```
AgentStatus s1;
s1.statusInfo = 0;
while(1){
    std::cout<<"scanner status = "<<s1.statusInfo<<std::endl;
    usleep(1000000);
}
```

the error I am getting is this:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘State’ [fpermissive]
 s1.statusInfo = 0;
```

How can I set my struct to one of those values in the state enum?

Comment: You defined an enum. Why wouldn't you write, `s1.statusInfo = OFFLINE;` instead of `s1.statusInfo = 0;`? As far as the C++ compiler is concerned, you've defined a type with specific values (enum values), and it expects you to use them. That's how enums work.

Comment: You have to use a static_cast

Comment: Why would you define a struct that contains only one element?  Are you, like, enchanted with structures?  Just use a flippin' scalar State!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implicitly convert from a `State` to a number, but not from a number to a `State`.

Try either

```
s1.statusInfo = OFFLINE;
```

or

```
s1.statusInfo = static_cast<State>(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined:

```
enum State {
    OFFLINE = 0,
    ONLINE = 1,
    ...
};
```

but then you do:

```
s1.statusInfo = 0;
```

which would require a cast, you can/should(readability, maintenance..) avoid it though, by doing this:

```
s1.statusInfo = OFFLINE;
```

---

Minimal example:

```
enum State {
    OFFLINE = 0,
    ONLINE = 1,
};

struct AgentStatus {
    State statusInfo;
};

int main() {
    AgentStatus s1;
    s1.statusInfo = OFFLINE;
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall main.cpp
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$
```